# Cascading multiple choice column

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery

I have implemented cascading in a multiple choice filed.
Now my requirement is if I have 10 items in this column then I need only four of them so I have tried removing is using Jquery.

```
$("select[title='field possible values']")
    .find('option')
    .remove()
    .end()
    .append('<option value="China">China</option>')
    .val('China')
;
```

This works but when I add this value to `field selected values` field and again remove it from there, then all values appear in `field possible values` field.

This means the muliple select dropdown values were not removed from the `field possible value` field permanently.

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. But I was able to solve using SPServices.CascadeDropdowns. See below links for answers.

http://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/value-added/SPCascadeDropdowns.html

[How I populate 2nd choice column depending on 1st choice column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/220055/how-i-populate-2nd-choice-column-depending-on-1st-choice-column)