# How I populate 2nd choice column depending on 1st choice column

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, cascading

How can I populate 2nd choice column based on the 1st choice column?

**For ex.:** 1st column, 1st option - Veg Food, 2nd option - Non-Veg Food. If the user selects Veg Food option, then in the second column will be shown choices A,B,C. If user chooses Non-Veg Food, then in the second column will be shown only choices X,Y,Z

I don't want to use any code to have this change. I have an access to Designer and InfoPath.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve cascading in SharePoint through multiple ways as the following.

1. Using javascript `SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns`.
2. [Using Infopath data connection and some rules.](http://www.spums.be/?p=241) by the way, this option requires SharePoint Enterprise Edition
3. Develop a Custom Field using C#.

Based on your knowledge you can select the preferred option.

---

Here I will show to you the first options using `SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns`,

- Open your list,
- From the above ribbon, select `Default New form`,

[image]

- Add a new Script Editor web part
- Add the below code by specifying the parent and child lookup field

**Script:**

```
<script src="https://site name/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://sitename/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function ()  
{  
    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns(  
    {  
        relationshipList: "Column2",  
        relationshipListParentColumn: "Column1",  
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",  
        parentColumn: "Column1",  
        childColumn: "Column2",  
        debug: true  
    });  
});  
</script>
```

For the detail, steps check

- [Cascading of Lookup Dropdown Fields on SharePoint 2013](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/cascading-of-lookup-dropdown-fields-on-sharepoint-2013-and-o/)
- [Two Level Cascading Drop Down in SharePoint 2013 using SPServices](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/758909/Two-Level-Cascading-Drop-Down-in-SharePoint-using)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a case for Dr. SharePoint Hillbilly

http://www.markrackley.net/2017/03/06/new-improved-cascading-dropdowns-for-sharepoint-classic-forms/